# Remove rows from csv document using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, csv

So currently I have the following VBA code, what this does is it collects a csv from a dedicated directory.

```
Sub UploadData()

' Define the relative variables
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlManual

' Define the variables necessary
Dim Path As String
Dim DataFile1 As String
Dim datasheet As String
Dim Temp_File_Name1 As String
Dim File_Name1 As String

' Set the path locations to grab the 151_.csv file
Path1 = Worksheets("FileNames").Cells(25, 3).Value
DataFile1 = Worksheets("FileNames").Cells(29, 3).Value

' ------------------------------------------- Send the csv file as an email ------------------------------------------------- '
' Assign the path directory to the csv file
Temp_File_Name1 = Path1 & DataFile1 & "*.csv"
File_Name1 = Dir(Temp_File_Name1)
File_Name1 = Path1 & File_Name1

End Sub
```

The CSV file retrieved is in the following format, where my goal is to remove the rows that have the "pipeline_point_code" 30000001PC as depicted in the following image.

[image]

Is it possible to remove these rows from the csv through the vba code? If not, how can I paste this csv stored in the "File_Name1" variable into my excel sheet that is labelled "Data"

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly this isn't about reading content of a .CSV file. Instead, you want to loop over all the filenames in a folder, list the filenames in a sheet, and then exclude certain filenames, is that correct?

You can use `Dir()` without parameters to iterate over the files, like so:

```
Dim FileName As String
Dim folder as String
Dim rownum As Integer

' get starting folder
folder = Worksheets("FileNames").Cells(25, 3).Value

' start iterating all files
FileName = Dir(folder + "\*.csv", vbDirectory)
rownum = 1

' iterate all files
Do While FileName <> ""
    ' add to Data sheet, but filter out "pipeline_point_code" file name
    If (FileName <> "pipeline_point_code") Then 
        rownum = rownum + 1
        Worksheets("Data").Cells(rownum, 1).Value = FileName
    End If
    ' next file
    FileName = Dir()
Loop
```